# SQL регулярные выражения - удаление точки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

просьба подсказать, что делаю не так.
Суть в том, что необходимо из таблицы dealer в столбце contract удалить все символы, которые идут в конце строки, и могут содержать (".","..","","/","_")
В столбце контракт есть такие значения:

- 100001-04..
- 100003-04.
- 100004-04./пилот
- 100005-04/пилот
- 100006-04\пилот
- 100007-04.\пилот
- 100008-04..
- 100008-04_

В результате все символы и любой текст, что идет после "-04", должны быть удалены.

Использую следующий запрос:

```
SELECT
(
case 
when contract like '%/%' then regexp_replace(contract,'\\.*$','') -- ищем символ "/" и заменяем его и все что идет после пустой строкой
when contract like '%\\%' then regexp_replace(contract,'\\.*$','') -- ищем символ "\" и заменяем его и все что идет после пустой строкой
when contract like '%_%' then regexp_replace(contract,'\_*$','','g') -- ищем символ "_" и заменяем его и все что идет после пустой строкой
when contract like '%.' then regexp_replace(contract, '\\.\\s*$', '') -- ищем точку "." и заменяем ее и все что идет после пустой строкой
else contract -- если ничего не нашли выводим как есть
end
) as contract
FROM dealer as t1
```

В итоге код работает на всем, кроме "." и ".."
В таблице все равно остаются записи

- 100001-04..
- 100003-04.

Н совесм понимаю, как от них избавится. БД POSTGRESQL

Comment: У вас очень странный код. Сложно понять что вы хотели им "сказать". Лучше будет, если вы отредактируете свой вопрос у укажите для каждой строки примера, какой результат вы хотите получить.  А так чисто, навскидку, точка является служебным символом в регулярных выражениях. И ее нужно экранировать,

Comment: @newman отредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte (raw_value) AS (
SELECT '100001-04..' UNION ALL
SELECT '100003-04.' UNION ALL
SELECT '100004-04./пилот' UNION ALL
SELECT '100005-04/пилот' UNION ALL
SELECT '100006-04\пилот' UNION ALL
SELECT '100007-04.\пилот' UNION ALL
SELECT '100008-04..' UNION ALL
SELECT '100008-04_'
)
SELECT raw_value, regexp_replace(raw_value, '^(.*\d)\D*$', '\1') clear_value
FROM cte
```

| raw_value | clear_value |
| --- | --- |
| 100001-04.. | 100001-04 |
| 100003-04. | 100003-04 |
| 100004-04./пилот | 100004-04 |
| 100005-04/пилот | 100005-04 |
| 100006-04\пилот | 100006-04 |
| 100007-04.\пилот | 100007-04 |
| 100008-04.. | 100008-04 |
| 100008-04_ | 100008-04 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zLnuDuW1)

Попросту отрезаем с задницы все нецифровые символы.